# Как указать путь до сертификата в конфигурации для Stunnel 5.65 (stunnel_msspi.exe)?

Tags: tls, криптопро

Существует конфигурация для службы **Stunnel** (на Windows):

```
output= C:\stunnel\stunnel_cli.log
socket= l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket= r:TCP_NODELAY=1
debug= 7

[https]
client= yes
accept= localhost:3080
connect= 00.000.00.000:3080
cert= C:\stunnel\stunnel.cer
verify= 0
```

Запуская службу (или напрямую exe), сервис запускается. Но пробую перейти на **localhost:3080**, сервис пробует получить сертификат, указанный в конфигурации и выдает следующие ошибки:

```
msspi: try open cert = "C:\stunnel\stunnel.cer" as file
msspi: add_mycert failed: "bad file format" (cert = "C:\stunnel\stunnel.cer")
```

Если указывать вместо пути - печать сертификата:

> cert= 2209e00c2d14f5f14046466ee5e05b94a9dbe430e

, то ничего не изменится, ошибка появится снова. Ставля пробелы после каждых 2-х символов, ничего не меняет (`22 09 .. 43 0e`).

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с аналогичной ошибкой, сначала зашел под пользователем, от имени которого запускается служба, заново поставил сертификат в "Личные" в "Сертификаты - Текущий пользователь - Личное - Реестр - Сертификаты", затем заново экспортировал сертификат прямо поверх C:\stunnel\мой_сертификат.cer, перезапустил службу и заработало.
В консоли сертификатов у меня сертификата не оказалось. Второй вариант - мой_сертификат.cer мог быть не тем сертификатом. Третий вариант - не был сохранен или указан пин-код контейнера.
Точно не знаю, что именно помогло